# Get TargetControlId of an AutoCompleteExtender in OnClientItemSelected Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I have a texbox inside a templatefield in a gridview. For this textbox I have defined an autocompleteextender with its TargetControlID set to "myTextbox" which is working just fine. At the same time, for the OnClientItemSelected property I have defined a javascript function which should set the value of my textbox, but my question is how can I get the the name of this textbox using javascript?

My control snippet like this:

```
ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender TargetControlID="txtValue" onClientItemSelected="SetValue"
```

And my code looks like this:

```
function SetValue(sender, eventArgs){
  var TitleValue = eventArgs.get_value(); 
  /* do smth with this value */
  /* set the new value to my textbox ? */
}
```

Your suggestions and ideas are very much appreciated. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get the textbox control using:

```
sender.get_element()
```

For extenders, `get_element()` returns the targeted control, for script controls, it's the element that represents that control.